# Graph for android

Tags: android, graph

I need a library for graph that works like this:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3}
graph.show(a)
```

Does it exist?

Answer (score 4):

you can refer open source java library for drawing graphs and charts.. [achartengine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)

Answer (score 1):

There was a pretty thorough question on something similar to this a while back, has my response in it too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156740/im-looking-for-fancy-charts-library-for-android/5157576#5157576

aiCharts is very easy to work with if you are looking for simplicity. Just gotta get it installed and running, then the source code is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

This chart library using js & HTML5

http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-chart/166221?ref=mhameen

you can use it in a web browser view

Answer (score 0):

Use GraphView http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html

That's very easy to use and powerful anyway.

Code for a simple chart with 4 points:

```
// init example series data
GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
      new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
      , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)
      , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)
      , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)
});

GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(
      this // context
      , "GraphViewDemo" // heading
);
graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.addView(graphView);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use RGraph library from below link:
http://www.rgraph.net/download#stable

I used this library in project and I think its best and easy to use for all types of graphs like line, rect, bars, pie, etc. with some special animation effects!!